# What is a Nihilist and a Buddhist point of view on music and other forms of entertainment?

Tags: buddhism, nihilism

From what I know, Buddhism seeks to detach from every form of pleasure and craving, listening to music could be seen as a way of not being present in the moment, but I'm sure they too can enjoy music. Are some genres frowned upon more than others?

The question becomes clearer when we think about television, for other than their informative value, may a buddhist have a high regard for movies? What about action movies where dead and suffering is depicted?

There's and old episode of C.S.I. (Criminal scene investigation) where a buddhist monk is thought of as a suspect, and when cops search his room they find porn magazines. Thinking thats not very monk-like, cops go and talk with a buddhist teacher who goes on to explain how a buddhist monk could read porn magazines and find the same beauty as if he were watching pictures of waterfalls, without lifting any thought of lust or desire, watching women as what they really are, just animals, like watching a cow or a dog.

Maybe they are capable of doing this, but would they?

Comment: Buddhism is not Nihilism so your question is weird. And you never mention Nihilism explicitly besides in topic.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware they're not the same, I'm curious about both so I guess it's really a double question.

Comment: CSI is no good source for information about what buddhism is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nibbedhika Sutta* ([AN 6.63](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.063.than.html)) says:

```
The passion for his resolves is a man's sensuality,
not the beautiful sensual pleasures
    found in the world.
The passion for his resolves is a man's sensuality.

The beauties remain as they are in the world,
while the wise, in this regard,
    subdue their desire.
```

So beautiful material objects (of five senses) are 'strings of sensuality' (*kamaguna*). While they are certainly considered dangerous they are not in itself bad. (Also, seeing them could be results of good karma.) What is *bad* is to have *passion* for them (*kamaraga*).